# Subset $A$ of a sigma algebra satisfying three properties

Tags: measure-theory, logic

$\mathcal E$ is a sigma algebra of $S$. $E\in\mathcal E$. Is it possible to **find** a subset $A\subset \mathcal E$, satisfying the following three properties:

1. If $E\in A$, then $F\setminus E \in A^\complement$ for any $F$.
2. If $E\in A$, then $F\in A$ for all $F\supset E$. This means all superset of $E$ must be in $A$.
3. If $E\in A$, then there exists a finite partition of $S$: $\{B_1,B_2,...,B_n\}$, such that $\forall i: E\setminus B_i\in A$.

**My try to prove the statement is wrong and $A$ does not exist:**

First suppose that $E_0\in A$ and for no $E_1\subset E_0$ we have $E_1\in A$; this clearly violates property 3. So, if $E_0\in A_1$ there must be a $E_1$ also in $A$. Let's take the limit $\cap_\infty E_n$. There are three cases:

Case 1, the limit does not exist. This is not possible by the definition of sigma algebra. The countable intersection is also in $\mathcal E$.

Case 2, the limit exists and $\cap_\infty E_n\in A$. This case $\cap_\infty E_n$ violates property 3.

Case 3, the limit exists and $\cap_\infty E_n\in A^\complement$. I am stuck here. It is possible that the limit is an empty set.

**My try to find an example:**

Let $S$ be the set of natural numbers. Let **all** arithmetic sequence be in $A$. Suppose that all of the following sets are in $A$:

> {1,2,3,...}
>
> {4,8,12,...}
>
> {3,5,7,...}
>
> ...

Their super sets are also in $A$.

Here is two example sets that is *not* in $A$: $\{1,2,4,8,16,...\}$, $\{3,14,159,2653,58979,323846,...\}$

Do you think the set of all arithmetic sequences $\{an+b\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ (and their supersets) are a good example?

---

Of course, there is trivial $A=\{\emptyset\}$ which is not very interesting.

Comment: It is clear that the whole set $S$ is in $A$ if $A$ is nonempty. By property 1, the empty set must not in $A$.

Comment: @Ramiro Sorry but in my humble opinion the empty set is not in $A$ so we cannot apply property to empty sets. So we cannot simply conclude that all subsets are in $\mathcal E$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Ramiro O I don’t see how what you said follows, property 2 would require you to know $\emptyset\in A$ to conclude anything.

Comment: Property 3 seems odd.  Isn’t it equivalent if you make $\{B_i\}$ a partition of only $E$, rather than all of $S$? (Just replace each $B_i$ with $B_i\cap E$?)

Comment: @MW Could you please elaborate? Property 2 just says if $E$ in $A$ then all superset of $E$ must be in A.

Comment: @MW You are definitely correct for the implication of property 3. Your definition is equivalent.

Comment: @HighGPA my comment about property 2 was in response to the first comment by Ramiro, explaining the problem with his reasoning as I see it. I agree with you on this.

Answer (score 1):

[Clarification - I assume this question is asking whether it is possible for $A$ to exist ***for some*** $S$ and $\mathcal E$, not for every $S$ and $\mathcal E$.  It clearly does not exist, for example, in the case that $S$ is finite.]

$A$ can definitely exist.  Let $S=[0,1]$, let $\mathcal E$ be the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets, and let $A=\{E\in\mathcal E\mid |E|>\frac{1}{2}\}$.  Then the first two properties are immediate, and for the third, if $E\in A$ then $|E|>\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n$, so let $\{B_i\}$ be any finite partition of $[0,1]$ such that $|B_i\cap E|<\frac{1}{n}$ for each $i$.

Also, as an aside, arithmetic sequences and their supersets seem to fail property 1, since the set of even numbers and the set of odd numbers would both be in $A$.

Finally,  $A=\{\emptyset\}$ cannot satisfy 1, even as a trivial example, since $\emptyset\backslash \emptyset = \emptyset$.

Comment: You are definitely correct. It is for some $S$ and $\mathcal E$